# Page losing focus

Tags: javascript, focus

Hi I have a small javascript function I am calling after updating a grid using ajax.  I ran into a problem with losing page focus after refreshing the grid. I am trying to use the following code to get the active element, refresh the grid, then reset focus to its previous state.

```
var selectedTextArea = document.activeElement;
grid1.refresh();
document.getElementById(selectedTextArea.id).focus();
```

This seems to work except that the focus is being set before the refresh has finished executing so the page still loses focus.  Any ideas on why this is happeneing and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You should set the focus after the AJAX call was finished successfully. You need to provide a callback function somehow to your `refresh()` function. If you show us your `refresh()` function we could help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your grid refresh function is performing an asyc operation.
You will need to capture your grid finishing its refresh, and performing your focus call there.

It is a little difficult to answer in more detail without knowing what framework you are using to build your grid or what refreshing the grid entails.  More details will likely give more complete results.

Comment: The grid control is an Obout inc grid.  It has its own refresh function which I am calling.